# Code to get XML or Json on Java

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the data that come from these * link*
http://21.26.54.26/swapi/api/data/json
http://21.26.54.26/swapi/api/data/xml

I tried many methods but in the end it always gives me error when it goes through this line  `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);`

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://********/swapi/api/data/xml")
                    .build();


            Response responses = null;

            try {
                responses = client.newCall(request).execute();

                json = responses.body().string();

                System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

                try {


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);


                    //   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonObj);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Carro");
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("idintelisis");
                        System.out.println("TESTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE: " + id);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException ex) {

                    System.out.println("Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr: " + ex);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is the error ** long ** that throws when it breaks on that line

> 01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"},{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:114)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:65)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf I/System.out: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"},{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I use ** Postman ** to check the result of the ** Json ** and also the ** Json ** of the ** log ** and everything indicates that the ** Json ** is correct in terms of structure I do not understand What breaks when trying to convert it to a * Json * object *

Comment: Look at the data again. The data is not pure `JSON`. Its wrapped in `<string></string>` tags. So its `JSON` wrapped in `XML`. Once you get the `JSON` out you can use @Jayanths answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because what you are getting is `JsonArray` not `JsonObject`

try this

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray(obtained_result);
```

and then try to get `JsonObject` from `arr` using `getJSONObject(index)` method

Example:

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray(obtained_result);
   for(int i = 0; i< arr.length(); i++){
   JsonObject ob = arr.getJSONObject(i);
}
```